# Related_name is returning an attribute error (NoneType) from a Django Forms. I'm trying to create a dynamic filter within forms

Tags: python, django

I'm using Django 3.1.4 with Python 3.7.8. I wanted to have form field for my `ProductForm` to automatically filter `Category` and `Subcategory`.

I followed the suggest from https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/01/29/how-to-implement-dependent-or-chained-dropdown-list-with-django.html. However I keep getting an error, `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'list_of_subcategories'`.

I used Django shell to see if my `related_name` would work. It the error keeps popping up.

Here is my `models.py`:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField(
        default=slugify(name),
        unique=True
    )
    
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'category'
        verbose_name_plural = 'categories'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class SubCategory(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    category = models.ForeignKey(
        Category,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="list_of_subcategories"
    )

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Subcategory'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Subcategories'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Here is my `forms.py`:

```
class ProductForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = [
            'sku', 'name',
            'category', 'subcategory',
            'short_description', 'description',
            'price',
        ]
    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        self.fields['subcategory'].queryset = SubCategory.objects.none()

        if 'category' in self.data:
            try:
                category_id = int(self.data.get('category'))
                self.fields('subcategory').queryset = Category.objects.filter(category_id=category_id).order_by('name')
            except (ValueError, TypeError):
                pass
        elif self.instance.pk:
            self.fields['category'].queryset = self.instance.category.list_of_subcategories.order_by('name')
```

Here is my `views.py`:

```
def loadSubcategory(request):
    category_id = request.GET.get('category')
    subcategories = SubCategory.objects.filter(category_id=category_id).order_by('name')
    return render(request, 'product/subcategory_drop_down.html', {'subcategories': subcategories})


def createProduct(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = ProductForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            product_form = form.save(commit=False)
            product_form.company = request.user.company
            product_form.save()
            return redirect('dashboard:my_store')
    else:
        product_form = ProductForm()
        return render(request, 'product/create_product.html', {'product_form': product_form})
```

Lastly, here is the part of my html template:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $("#id_category").change(function () {
      var url = $("#productForm").attr("data-subcategories-url");  
      var categoryId = $(this).val();  

      $.ajax({                       
        url: url,                    
        data: {
          'category': categoryId     
        },
        success: function (data) {   
          $("#id_subcategory").html(data);
        }
      });

    });
</script>
```

Prior to this, I was successful in producing the dynamic filtering - when I click `Category`, the appropriate `SubCategory` pops up. I just couldn't submit the form. I've been stuck for a while now trying to figure out why it's returning a `NoneType` when I added this specific code within the `forms.py`:

```
if 'category' in self.data:
            try:
                category_id = int(self.data.get('category'))
                self.fields('subcategory').queryset = Category.objects.filter(category_id=category_id).order_by('name')
            except (ValueError, TypeError):
                pass
        elif self.instance.pk:
            self.fields['category'].queryset = self.instance.category.list_of_subcategories.order_by('name')
```

Traceback are as follows:

```
web_1  | Internal Server Error: /products/create-product/
web_1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
web_1  |     response = get_response(request)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 179, in _get_response
web_1  |     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
web_1  |   File "/platform/products/views.py", line 67, in createProduct
web_1  |     product_form = ProductForm()
web_1  |   File "/platform/products/forms.py", line 30, in __init__
web_1  |     self.fields['category'].queryset = self.instance.category.list_of_subcategories.order_by('name')
web_1  | AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'list_of_subcategories'
web_1  | [11/Feb/2021 17:19:02] "GET /products/create-product/ HTTP/1.1" 500 62639
```

Comment: Can you include the full error/stacktrace that you get in your console?

Comment: Apologies for the inconvenience. I just attached it now. Appreciate the help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no category associated with the instance, which is why you're getting that error.

If you consider the error, the thing that's trying to use `list_of_subcategories` is `self.instance.category`, so if `NoneType` doesn't have `list_of_subcategories`, then `category` is `None`.

So before you try to access the associated category, you should check that it exists, rather than checking the instance has a primary key;

```py
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            super().__init__(*args,**kwargs)
            self.fields['subcategory'].queryset = SubCategory.objects.none()
    
            if 'category' in self.data:
                try:
                    category_id = int(self.data.get('category'))
                    self.fields('subcategory').queryset = Category.objects.filter(category_id=category_id).order_by('name')
                except (ValueError, TypeError):
                    pass
            elif self.instance.category:
                self.fields['category'].queryset = self.instance.category.list_of_subcategories.order_by('name')
```